# Slice of Radio and Wirelessthings sensor timing out when configuring (868Mhz)

Tags: wireless, sensor

I bought the [Slice of Radio](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/slice-of-radio-wireless-rf-transciever-for-the-raspberry-pi) and a couple of [wireless thermometers](http://www.icode.co.uk/icatcher/cctvshop/wireless-humidity-and-temperature-sensor-lb-ca-white-p-1164.html) (all 868MHz) from Wirelessthings, that unfortunately went out of business at the same time I got the stuff and now their website is also not working.

I installed the Slice of Radio on a Raspberry Pi Model B+. All example images online show it with the original 26-pin Raspberry Pi ([example](https://www.fabtolab.com/image/cache/data/Microcontrollers/Raspberry%20Pi/Slice%20of%20Radio%20-%20Wireless%20RF%20transciever%20for%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%201-900x700.jpg)). I just slid in on the first 2x13 pins from the corner. I managed to upgrade the firmware on the radio board so maybe the pins are correct. The heart beat led on the board is blinking.

I also bought a couple of the [LB-CA temperature and humidity sensor](http://www.icode.co.uk/icatcher/cctvshop/wireless-humidity-and-temperature-sensor-lb-ca-white-p-1164.html). I have followed the [guidelines](https://github.com/WirelessThings/WirelessThings-LaunchPad/blob/master/Documentation/WirelessThings%20LaunchPad%20User%20Guide.pdf) on how to setup the radio and the sensors. Everything is working as documented except that when I'm pressing the config button on the sensor, nothing happens on the Raspberry.

I also flashed the Slice of Radio with the newest firmware from [here](https://github.com/CisecoPlc/XRF-Firmware-downloads/tree/master/Slice%20of%20Radio%20SRF). Before that I couldn't connect to the radio board with the [MessageBridge](https://github.com/WirelessThings/WirelessThings-LaunchPad/tree/master/MessageBridge) software specified in the guide mentioned above.

I'm not so familiar with wireless connections but I ran the following script

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
   
    port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)         

while 1:
    x=ser.readline()
    print x
```

This produced nothing, even when I was pushing the button on the sensor. I bought several sensors and I can't this working with any of them.

My questions:

1. Is it ok to put the Slice of Radio on the first 2x13 pins on a model B+ Raspberry Pi or do I need to change some setting.
2. A led is flashing in the sensors and I assume they are sending on the 868MHz frequency stated on them. Should this traffic be somehow seen on the Raspberry running the above script, indicating that there is some transmission going on?
3. Any pointers as to what is the problem.

**More debug information**

In MessageBridge.cfg I have

> [Serial]
> network_use_radio_serial_number = False
> network = Serial
> baudrate = 9600
> port = /dev/ttyAMA0
> at_gpio = False
> at_gpio_pin = 16

When starting MessageBridge with python MessageBridge.py -d -l DEBUG I get:

> 2016-10-02 18:34:28,314 - Message Bridge - INFO - Serial port init
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:28,327 - Message Bridge - INFO - tSerial: Serial thread started
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,327 - Message Bridge - INFO - DCR Thread init
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,334 - Message Bridge - INFO - tSerial: Opened the serial port
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,347 - Message Bridge - INFO - UDP Send Thread init
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,346 - Message Bridge - INFO - tDCR: DCR thread started
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,360 - Message Bridge - INFO - UDP Listen Thread init
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,366 - Message Bridge - INFO - tUDPSend: Send thread started
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,374 - Message Bridge - INFO - tUDPListen: UDP listen thread started
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,381 - Message Bridge - INFO - tUDPListen: listening
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,446 - Message Bridge - INFO - tSerial: Setting ATLH1
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:29,450 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Enter Command Mode
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:30,555 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,466 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,470 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATVR
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,474 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for Response
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,499 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,503 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,507 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tSerial: FW Version: 96B SORSRF
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,511 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATSN
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,515 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for Response
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,531 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,536 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,540 - Message Bridge - INFO - tSerial: Radio Serial Number: 000001
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,544 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATLH
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,549 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for Response
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,563 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,568 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,572 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATID
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,576 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for Response
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,591 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,596 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,600 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATEE
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,604 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for Response
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,619 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,623 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,628 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATEK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,632 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for Response
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,680 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,684 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,688 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Leave Command Mode
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,693 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Send command: ATDN
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,697 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Wait for OK
>
> 2016-10-02 18:34:31,710 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - AT: Got OK

**And then it continues like this when running ConfigurationWizard**

> 2016-10-02 18:40:51,279 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"type": "MessageBridge", "network": "ALL"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 59370)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:51,284 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type MessageBridge, passing to qMessageBridge
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:51,377 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Processing MessageBridge JSON message
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:51,382 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Put {'timestamp': '02 Oct 2016 18:40:51 +0000', 'state': 'Running', u'type': u'MessageBridge', u'network': 'Serial'} on qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:51,410 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:40:51 +0000", "state": "Running", "type": "MessageBridge", "network": "Serial"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:51,421 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:57,814 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"type": "MessageBridge", "network": "ALL"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 59370)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:57,819 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type MessageBridge, passing to qMessageBridge
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:57,907 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Processing MessageBridge JSON message
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:57,912 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Put {'timestamp': '02 Oct 2016 18:40:57 +0000', 'state': 'Running', u'type': u'MessageBridge', u'network': 'Serial'} on qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:57,949 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:40:57 +0000", "state": "Running", "type": "MessageBridge", "network": "Serial"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:40:57,954 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:02,806 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"type": "MessageBridge", "network": "ALL"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 59370)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:02,810 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type MessageBridge, passing to qMessageBridge
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:02,927 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Processing MessageBridge JSON message
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:02,931 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Put {'timestamp': '02 Oct 2016 18:41:02 +0000', 'state': 'Running', u'type': u'MessageBridge', u'network': 'Serial'} on qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:02,941 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:41:02 +0000", "state": "Running", "type": "MessageBridge", "network": "Serial"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:02,951 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:06,648 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "id": "179a2417-525e-4361-bc36-b6312bbc7068", "timeout": 30}, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "network": "Serial"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 59370)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:06,653 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type DeviceConfigurationRequest, passing to qDCRRequest
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:06,856 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Got a request to process
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:06,861 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: started DCR timeout with period: 30
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:36,915 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: DCR timeout expired
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:36,919 - Message Bridge - WARNING - tDCR: Failed current DCR due to timeout
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:36,926 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: removed stale query from qSerialToQuery
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:36,934 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Sent DCR reply to qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:36,959 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"keepAwake": 0, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "state": "FAIL_TIMEOUT", "id": "179a2417-525e-4361-bc36-b6312bbc7068", "timeout": 30, "replies": {}}, "network": "Serial", "timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:41:36 +0000"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:36,970 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:49,678 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "id": "179a2417-525e-4361-bc36-b6312bbc7068", "timeout": 30}, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "network": "Serial"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 59370)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:49,686 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type DeviceConfigurationRequest, passing to qDCRRequest
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:49,959 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Got a request to process
>
> 2016-10-02 18:41:49,964 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: started DCR timeout with period: 30
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:20,018 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: DCR timeout expired
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:20,022 - Message Bridge - WARNING - tDCR: Failed current DCR due to timeout
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:20,028 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: removed stale query from qSerialToQuery
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:20,038 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Sent DCR reply to qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:20,044 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"keepAwake": 0, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "state": "FAIL_TIMEOUT", "id": "179a2417-525e-4361-bc36-b6312bbc7068", "timeout": 30, "replies": {}}, "network": "Serial", "timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:42:20 +0000"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:20,054 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:38,399 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"type": "MessageBridge", "network": "ALL"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 49564)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:38,413 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type MessageBridge, passing to qMessageBridge
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:38,597 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Processing MessageBridge JSON message
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:38,602 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tMain: Put {'timestamp': '02 Oct 2016 18:42:38 +0000', 'state': 'Running', u'type': u'MessageBridge', u'network': 'Serial'} on qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:38,649 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:42:38 +0000", "state": "Running", "type": "MessageBridge", "network": "Serial"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:38,654 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:42,427 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "id": "3ebb9f28-319b-4494-b48b-2693a52531e3", "timeout": 30}, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "network": "Serial"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 49564)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:42,431 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type DeviceConfigurationRequest, passing to qDCRRequest
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:42,592 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Got a request to process
>
> 2016-10-02 18:42:42,598 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: started DCR timeout with period: 30
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:12,654 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: DCR timeout expired
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:12,658 - Message Bridge - WARNING - tDCR: Failed current DCR due to timeout
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:12,667 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: removed stale query from qSerialToQuery
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:12,679 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Sent DCR reply to qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:12,691 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"keepAwake": 0, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "state": "FAIL_TIMEOUT", "id": "3ebb9f28-319b-4494-b48b-2693a52531e3", "timeout": 30, "replies": {}}, "network": "Serial", "timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:43:12 +0000"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:12,698 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:23,803 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: Received JSON: {"data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "id": "3ebb9f28-319b-4494-b48b-2693a52531e3", "timeout": 30}, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "network": "Serial"} From: ('192.168.0.120', 49564)
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:23,808 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPListen: JSON of type DeviceConfigurationRequest, passing to qDCRRequest
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:24,203 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Got a request to process
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:24,208 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: started DCR timeout with period: 30
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:54,263 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: DCR timeout expired
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:54,267 - Message Bridge - WARNING - tDCR: Failed current DCR due to timeout
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:54,273 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: removed stale query from qSerialToQuery
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:54,282 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tDCR: Sent DCR reply to qUDPSend
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:54,307 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Got json to send: {"keepAwake": 0, "type": "DeviceConfigurationRequest", "data": {"toQuery": [{"command": "DTY"}, {"command": "APVER"}, {"command": "CHDEVID"}], "state": "FAIL_TIMEOUT", "id": "3ebb9f28-319b-4494-b48b-2693a52531e3", "timeout": 30, "replies": {}}, "network": "Serial", "timestamp": "02 Oct 2016 18:43:54 +0000"}
>
> 2016-10-02 18:43:54,312 - Message Bridge - DEBUG - tUDPSend: Put message out via UDP

And when running lsof /dev/ttyAMA0 from another terminal I get:

> COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> python  19304   pi    4u   CHR 204,64      0t0   12 /dev/ttyAMA0

So some kind of DeviceConfigurationRequest seems to be received but it times out. How can I fux this?

Answer (score 1):

You should see communication with MessageBridge when you run `./MessageBridge.py -d -l DEBUG` (but make sure you stop any running MessageBridge processes/services first).  Do you have same serial port configured in MessageBridge.cfg (careful, the MessageBridge.py script overwrites this on exit e.g. when killed)?  On a Raspberry Pi2, I have this serial section:

```
[Serial]
network = Serial
baudrate = 9600
port = /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Assuming you get confirmation of serial communication from MessageBridge, you should then be able to use ConfigurationWizard to do basic config on your sensors...

Finally, with MessageBridge running, you may want to check that it (and only it) is communicating with the serial port (e.g. `lsof /dev/ttyAMA0`).

If you can see MessageBridge successfully communicating with the Slice Of Radio (e.g. getting firmware version etc. successfully by sending AT commands), then you should be able to move on to using the Configuration Wizard to setup your sensors...  The setup interactions, and then also the sensor output should show up in the debug log, and also in:

`WirelessThings-LaunchPad/MessageBridge/CSVLogs/CSV_MessageBridge.csv`.

Comment: In the settings I have
[UDP]
send_port = 50140
listen_port = 50141
but in the log I can see
From: ('192.168.0.120', 49564)
and
From: ('192.168.0.120', 59370)

Are these at all related?